# Reading a file directly from HDFS into a shell function

Tags: file, hadoop, local, hdfs

I have a shell function that is called from inside my map function. The shell function takes 2 parameters -> an input file and an output file. Something like this

```
$> unix-binary /pathin/input.txt /pathout/output.txt
```

The problem is, that these input.txt files reside in HDFS and the output.txt files need to be written back to HDFS. Currently, I first copy the needed file with `fs.copyToLocalFile` into the local hard drive, call the unix binary and then write the output.txt back to HDFS with `fs.copyFromLocalFile`. 
The problem with this  approach is that, it is not optimal because it involves substantial amount of redundant reading and writing to HDD which slows down the performance. So, my question is, how I can read the HDFS file directly as an input and output the results directly to HDFS? 
obviously, 
`$>unix-binary hdfs://master:53410/pathin/input.txt' hdfs://master:54310/pathout/output.txt` 
will not work. Is there any other way around? Can I treat an HDFS file as a loacl file somehow? 
I have access to the unix-binary source code written in C. Maybe changing the source code would help?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the file to the [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) and access it from the mapper from the cache. Call your shell function on the local file and write the output file to local disk and then copy the local file to HDFS.

However, operations such as calling shell functions, or reading/writing from within a mapper/reducer break the MapReduce paradigm. If you find yourself needing to perform such operations, MapReduce may not be the solution you're looking for. HDFS and MapReduce were designed to perform massive scale batch processing on small numbers of extremely large files.

Since you have access to unix-binary source code, your best option might be to implement the particular function(s) you want in java. Feed the input files to your mapper and call the function from the mapper on the data rather than working with files on HDFS/LocalFS.